# How to connect a grails app to Consul through micronaut Http Client?

Tags: java, grails, consul, micronaut

I have a grails 3.2.0 web profile app. I want to connect to a separate micronaut app which is running fine and is connected properly to consul locally.

Here is my micronaut controller :

```
@Controller("/test")
class TestController {

    @Get("/")
    def index(){
        return "Welcome to micronaut"
    }

    @Get("/test")

    Single<String> test() {
        return Single.just("Hello There")
    }
}
```

Here is my grails controller :

```
class CardClientController {

    @Autowired
    NewCardClient newCardClient

    def index() {
        def result = newCardClient.getCards()
        respond result
    }
}
```

NewCardClient interface :

```
@Client("firstmicroservice")
public interface NewCardClient {

    @Get("/test/test")
    Single<String> getCards();

}
```

dependencies i've added in grails app :

```
compile 'io.micronaut:inject-java:1.0.0.M1'
compile 'io.micronaut:discovery-client:1.0.0.M1'
compile 'io.micronaut:spring:1.0.0.M1'
runtime 'io.micronaut:runtime:1.0.0.M1'
```

When i hit the grails controller as /cardClient/, i am getting following error:

```
2019-05-03 18:20:30.333 ERROR --- [nio-8200-exec-1] i.m.retry.intercept.RecoveryInterceptor  : Type [grailsmono.NewCardClient$Intercepted] executed with error: Cannot convert publisher into target type: class io.reactivex.Flowable

java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Cannot convert publisher into target type: class io.reactivex.Flowable
    at io.micronaut.cache.interceptor.CacheInterceptor.interceptPublisher(CacheInterceptor.java:352)
    at io.micronaut.cache.interceptor.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:120)
    at io.micronaut.aop.MethodInterceptor.intercept(MethodInterceptor.java:41)
    at io.micronaut.aop.chain.InterceptorChain.proceed(InterceptorChain.java:155)
    at io.micronaut.discovery.client.$CachingCompositeDiscoveryClientDefinition$Intercepted.getInstances(Unknown Source)
    at io.micronaut.discovery.client.CachingCompositeDiscoveryClient.getInstances(CachingCompositeDiscoveryClient.java:38)
    at io.micronaut.http.client.loadbalance.DiscoveryClientRoundRobinLoadBalancer.select(DiscoveryClientRoundRobinLoadBalancer.java:58)
    at io.micronaut.http.client.DefaultHttpClient.resolveRequestURI(DefaultHttpClient.java:720)
    at io.micronaut.http.client.DefaultHttpClient.exchange(DefaultHttpClient.java:410)
    at io.micronaut.http.client.DefaultHttpClient.exchange(DefaultHttpClient.java:154)
    at io.micronaut.http.client.HttpClient.retrieve(HttpClient.java:125)
    at io.micronaut.http.client.RxHttpClient.retrieve(RxHttpClient.java:60)
    at io.micronaut.http.client.RxHttpClient.retrieve(RxHttpClient.java:33)
    at io.micronaut.http.client.interceptor.HttpClientIntroductionAdvice.intercept(HttpClientIntroductionAdvice.java:331)
    at io.micronaut.aop.MethodInterceptor.intercept(MethodInterceptor.java:41)
    at io.micronaut.aop.chain.InterceptorChain.proceed(InterceptorChain.java:155)
    at io.micronaut.retry.intercept.RecoveryInterceptor.intercept(RecoveryInterceptor.java:74)
    at io.micronaut.aop.MethodInterceptor.intercept(MethodInterceptor.java:41)
    at io.micronaut.aop.chain.InterceptorChain.proceed(InterceptorChain.java:155)
    at grailsmono.NewCardClient$Intercepted.getCards(Unknown Source)
    ...
```

Couldn't connect to consul and not able to debug the cause. Please help!!!

Comment: I would also want to know if i can use micronaut client in Grails 2.5.6 app and could connect to consul. 
Thanks,

Comment: FYI... There is no good reason to be using that milestone release (`1.0.0.M1`) of Micronaut at this point.  We released 1.0.0 about 6 months ago and have released 5 or 6 releases since then.

Comment: @JeffScottBrown thanks a lot. I changed all the dependencies to 1.0.0.RC1 and it worked finally.

Comment: Why would you want to update from `1.0.0.M1` to  `1.0.0.RC1` 7 months after `1.0.0` was released?  There is no good reason to use the `RC` at this point.

Comment: @JeffScottBrown i had not added mavenCentral() repo as dependency so could only find 1.0.0.RC2 as latest for each dependencies. Now i am getting latest dependencies as 1.1.0 for all and working well. Thanks again.

Comment: @JeffScottBrown is the workaround different for grails version 2.5.6 or (<3)? My actual app is in grails 2.5.6 so when i tried to run it for grails 2.5.6 with same codes i got "No available services for ID: firstmicroservice" exception. 
Consul is up and running and so does the microservice.

Please HELP!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of @JeffScottBrown, my workaround got simple just by changing the dependencies version of each as follows :

Added mavenCentral() repository as dependency :

```
repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://repo.grails.org/grails/core" }

}
```

and the required micronaut dependencies as follows :

```
compile 'io.micronaut:micronaut-inject-java:1.1.0'
compile 'io.micronaut:micronaut-discovery-client:1.1.0'
compile 'io.micronaut:micronaut-spring:1.1.0'
runtime 'io.micronaut:micronaut-runtime:1.1.0'
```